# Objective-c action before closing the window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, window

How can i assign an action for close button in my window in objective-c?
For example, user clicks on close button and then program asks: "Do you really want to close the window?"

Comment: Close application or some inner view?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to connect the click on a button to a method call, or how display a window which asks the user something or how to close the window OR all of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add message before closing view in Application you need to implement UIAlertView in it, don't forget to add < UIAlertViewDelegate> in .h file

code in action button pressed;

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" 
                                                message:@"Do you really want to close the window?" 
                                                delegate:self 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

If you want to do something when the button is clicked, implement this delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        // the user clicked OK
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            // Write Close Code here.....

   }
}
```

Comment: @ElTomato Yes that really interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Define an uialertview

```
UIAlertView *message;
message= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"LOGOUT!" message:@"Are you sure to Logout of This app?" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         case :
    {

                 [message show];
                 vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginVC"];
                 [[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] popAllAndSwitchToViewController:vc withCompletion:nil];
                                  break;}

                        }
                        default:

                            break;

    }
```